# Illuminate Eloquent manipulate result

Tags: php, eloquent

In Eloquent 5.2.7 I was able to add to the result set using

```
foreach($page as $xp => $xv) {
    $content[0]->{$xp} = $xv;
}
```

Where `$content` was a `DB::table()->get()` result.

Now, on the latest version I get the following errors:

**Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Support\Collection has no effect in**

and

**Undefined offset: 0 in /vendor/illuminate/support/Collection.php**

I think I understand the why, and it's to do with PHP and `ArrayAccess` and `offsetGet` but I cannot figure out how to effectively do what I am doing "the right way"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the collection `map()` method to loop through and modify the results:

```
DB::table()->get()->map(function($content) use ($page) {
    foreach($page as $xp => $xv) {
        $content->{$xp} = $xv;
    }

    return $content;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this method better.

Answer (score 0):

After some more debugging, looks like I can manipulate the data like that, I just cannot pass it empty data - will need to check for empty arrays.

Also in order to display I needed to add `$content->all()`.